# Django external api calls

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a trouble calling external api. This is my view:

```
class TestView(APIView):

    def call_api(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        headers = {}
        url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'
        method = request.method.lower()
        method_map = {
            'get': requests.get,
            'post': requests.post,
            'put': requests.put,
            'patch': requests.patch,
            'delete': requests.delete
        }
        return Response(method_map[method](url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(request.data)).json())

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.call_api(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.call_api(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.call_api(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.call_api(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.call_api(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is my urls.py:

```
url(r'^test/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', TestView.as_view()),
```

How can i update my urls and call_api() to get one of users: test/1/ - go to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1, test/2 - go to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users//2. Now i have all users in that urls.py. Also i need this for all REST requests. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your url already supports calling test/1/ etc.

Comment: Yes, but on this url i get http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/, and i need go to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1

Comment: But that's the responsibility of `call_api`, surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `call_api` to

```
def call_api(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    headers = {}
    url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+args[0]
    # args[0] = pk
```

Comment: could do with a little more explanation